How to upload an image file to a MacOS app?
I'm creating an app which requires the user to upload image files to the app.
In the app I want to obtain its info (dimensions, ecc.) and show it.
Here is what I tried:
var body: some View {
     Button(action: {
         importing = true
     })
     {
         ...
     }
     .fileImporter(
         isPresented: $importing,
         allowedContentTypes: [.image]
     ) { result in
         switch result {
             case .success(let file):
                 print("File URL: \(file)")
             if controlImage(imageURL: file) {
                     print("Image uploaded successfully.")
                 } else {
                     print("Image doesn't match required dimensions.")
                 }
             case .failure(let error):
                 print("Failed to load the file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
             }
     }
 }
 
 func controlImage(imageURL: URL) -> Bool {
     print("Uploading image: \(imageURL.path)")
     
     let image: NSImage = NSImage(contentsOf: imageURL)!
     let imageWidth = image.size.width
     let imageHeight = image.size.height
     ...
 }

But when I create the NSImage it says:

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
value

although the image exists and also its URL.

What is your question?

Note that force-unwrapping (! operator) is a bad idea here. If the user picks an image file that can't be loaded, your code will crash. You should get rid of the force-unwrapping in your controlImage() function and add error handling that reports errors to the user instead.

@DuncanC Yes, I know it's not a good idea (thanks for reminding me), it is only for the moment to ensure it works. Then I should adjust that part of code. Thanks

The problem was caused by the File Access options of the Xcode project. By setting them to "Read/Write", the image is read correctly.


I agree with Duncan but it would be helpful if the answer provided more explicit instructions for others.

@Marcy I have updated the answer. I hope this will be more helpful.
